# Debug a WPF window or Windows Form without running your application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to WPF and have a question which quite same with the article: "Walkthrough: Debug a WPF window or Windows Form without running your application".

The link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/17/walkthrough-debug-a-wpf-window-or-windows-form-without-running-your-application-video.aspx

I will take the picture as an example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/habibh/WindowsLiveWriter/DebugaWPFwindoworWindowsFormwithoutrunni_FD38/image_3.png

From the picture, the project have 4 WPF windows such as:

1. App.xaml
2. Create...so on.xaml
3. MainWindows.xaml
4. ViewChart... so on.xaml

When every time in VS 2010, I click on the starting debugging (F5) or start without debugging(Ctrl + F5) will always run the MainWindows.xaml. What the reason coz this? Is this because of in the App.xaml that we declare StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml".

Can I run the particular WPF windows such number 4. ViewChart... so on.xaml instead of the whole application(*Such as the MainWindows.xaml)?

Comment: Indeed, StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" decides the main application frame window that will be displayed first. With WPF you can try use Blend to see the other windows but the debugging functionality is very limited. You can provide sample data for binding, so you can kind of debug a few things.

Comment: Tony, What should I do if I just want to run particular WPF windows instead MainWindows.xaml. I know that changing the StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" will get the job done. But assume that in the future I have numbers of WPF windows and each time need to run the particular windows need to change the startup file name will be a tedious work @.@ Got any solution to this?
Thks for replying me ~~

Comment: Tony, You mean create navigation features that allow us to go to the particular WPF windows during the run time?

Comment: You could try do that. I can only share my experiences. In the past, when I had to unit test complex dialog boxes I created separate applications. That involves being extra careful about sharing the code, so that you don't need to constantly update your own test cases. I used Blend for Data binding debugging the whole app.

Comment: Tony, Thanks for sharing your experience with me. Then I will try it ~~

Comment: You can bind in app.xaml's code-behind and use a variable to set the window you want... There certainly is a xaml way but I just woke up :P... What would be not-tedious to you? What you guys are talking about is an overkill esp if you don't need it (i.e. it's exclusively for debugging) imo...

Comment: For a smaller app, with say 6 dialogs of small complexity, creating 6 separate apps, just to debug each one, would definitely be an overkill. So would be the navigation infrastructure just to support it. For a large app, however, that can be a blessing in disguise. It forces developers to separate the concerns, make functionality modular and isolate custom GUI controls. I am talking here about testability more than standard debugging work, even if both ultimately serve to arrive at the well-behaved application.

Answer (score 6):

The article you linked is out of date and the video that demonstrates his solution is no longer hosted.  However, the basic steps that were outlined in the video are still possible, though the process can be more trouble than it's worth.

The process is as follows:

1. Open the Immediate Debugger window (Debug -> Windows -> Immediate Window)
2. In the Immediate mode, create an instance of the window you are wishing to test.
3. call the `ShowDialog()` method on your Immediate instance.

The main trouble with this method of debugging is that if your window has a complex constructor or has dependencies on external objects, you may end up spending more time setting up the dependencies than just navigating to the page would have taken.

Comment: Cool, how did you know what the method in the video was without watching it though (or is it that you just have a very good memory) :P...

Comment: it's been referenced a few obscure places, not to mention watching coworkers mess with the idea (with varying degrees of success)

Comment: Thks for your reply & I tried it but I have this error: "'((System.Windows.Window)($w))' is null"...May I ask that what the meaning of this?

Besides that my method of creating instance is correct or not?

    ? Windows w = new Windows();
    ? w.ShowDialog();

If I'm wrong can you correct me :) 
Any comment is welcome.

Comment: the method for creating an instance of a specific xaml window is the same in the immediate window as it is in your code... do you have code in your button click handlers that spawns the other windows or do you use some other means? like `var viewChart = new ViewChart(); viewChart.ShowDialog()`